# How to delete 100k + files from root?

Tags: php

i need to delete 100K + files from outside www directory recently i try to use below code which someone suggested me

```
foreach(glob('*.*') as $file) unlink($file);
```

but its delete files from public_html folder and i want to delete files from outside www directory

Thanks

Comment: Uhm, use a different path then? Like `/*` instead of `*.*`?

Comment: @deceze sorry i am new in PHP i didnt get your point

Comment: Btw, if you run this on your root folder, won't it delete `everything`, wipe out the system. Just a question, though. I don't see how you are accessing the desired 100K+ files being accesses anywhere.

Comment: @Pushpesh i have only unnecessary files in my root and other things in directory and i am able to see my root from ftp and cpanel file manager

Comment: No it won't. Unlink takes a single filename.  Taking up Pushpesh's point.  You need to think about what you _don't_ want to remove from / because if you don't do this, then you will be left with a dead system.

Comment: ok so i can put 3000 file ext but i want to delete these 100k + files which is created by cron

Comment: With such a massive amount of files I suggest you use the `find` command instead of shell expansion `*.*`. Also it's easier to test if it works in an interactive shell instead of the PHP script. After you have got a working command, invoke it via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
glob('/*.*')
```

it's not recursive.
The script should have permissions for deleting files from root.

Comment: i can able to delete files manually so the script also have the permission right?

Comment: If you run script manually (from console for example) - Yes. In this case script take your permissions and can do anything what you can.

Comment: i upload this file in public_html and thn open this file URL its simply load the page

Comment: @DanishIqbal In this case your script runs from another user and have permissions of this user. often this user is www-data (for debian based systems).

Comment: is there any way to open root file in browser ?

Comment: 1) Give permissions to this user for deleting this files. 2) Look at suPHP

Comment: how/where can i give permission to delete files 

what is suPHP

Comment: suPHP - http://www.suphp.org/Home.html. http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html You should give your script permissions for write in the root directory

Comment: i can able to delete files manually from root so i think i already have the permissions to do this what do you say

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is why you would want a publicly available script to have any access to your root folder.

If you're using this script from the command line to do some tasks then fine, but I highly recommend not to have any script in public_html modify files in your root folder.

If you still want to grant your script access to the root folder you can

```
chmod -R www-data:www-data /root/folder
```

and iterate through all folders and delete the files.

Comment: i just want to remove these files and where can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Webarto told me to change

```
foreach(glob('*.*') as $file) unlink($file);
```

to

```
foreach(glob('../*.*') as $file) unlink($file);
```

and its work successfully